# how to save html in redis cache rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

I want to save html in redis cache rails

```
def cache(cache_name)
  Rails.cache.fetch(cache_name, expires_in: 5.minutes){ yield }
end
```

in view

```
<% cache("key") do %>
  <h1>Header</h1>
<%end%>
```

because html not render after saving

Comment: So my updated solution didn't work?

Comment: no :(.......................

Comment: you changed the name of your helper? It worked on my machine..did you clear cache first? `Rails.cache.clear`?

Comment: how you do that?

Comment: Type `Rails.cache.clear` in your console and hit enter